# You are not authorized to view this page

Tags: iis, php

IIS 6, PHP 5, I set everything up and when I try to hit 127.0.0.1 which should serve index.php I get "You are not authorized to view this page" and some stuff about ACL preventing it.

How does one fix this? I dont want to mess up security on the directories in wwwroot. What permissions should work here?

Comment: does http://127.0.0.1/index.php work? If so, then you need to tell IIS to look for index.php files as its DirectoryIndex (that's what Apache calls it - I'm not sure what it's called in IIS land).

Comment: @ErikA - yes, that is valid. Same think happens when I try one of my sites that is PHP too.

Comment: Can you summarize what you did to "set everything up"?

Answer (score 1):

Add index.php to the Default Documents list in the website configuration in IIS:

[image]
<sub>(source: [php.net](http://www.php.net/manual/en/images/b4cf2bb34e3c20eebcf8f9e8e7949efd-iis6defaultdoc.png))</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Make sure IIS is configured properly.  Never used it never will but thats usually what happens when you get permission errors.